# Proving a perfect hash function over a fixed length input

Tags: algorithm, hash, proof

I have seen the answers on here stating to use gperf, however, I would prefer to roll my own based on the proof that I create for the domain of `strings` with a fixed length of `<= 200`  Based on the calculations I have from wolfram I get `~7.9 x 10^374` total permutations.  Therefore my line of thinking is if I have a `2048` bit hash function (`3.2 x 10^616`) I should be able to handle the entire universe of strings that I need to process. My question is how can I prove that the hash implementation I end up producing will be perfect given the constraint of the universe of all strings of length 200 or less?

Comment: @interjay It being useful is more of a theoretical concept :) .  So you propose that if I take each string that I have and convert it to a byte[] then apply a padding scheme to it I should have a no collision solution?  If that is the case how do I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings with a length of 200 characters only have 200 * 8 = 1600 bits. If a 2048 bit hash is OK for your purpose, you could just use the string bits as a perfect hash. The identity hash function is perfect, as it maps each input to a distinct hash value (obviously, because there is no mapping).

Comment: I chose 2048 as it was the next value above 1024 that would hold the universe.  Does this have any unintended consequences?